# Apply a where clause to edmx table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is there a way of applying a where clause to a table in the entities.edmx (EF6) for an MVC application?

I have a table called ceremony and I wish to only display the venues where the ceremony has already taken place (where year <= 2014). I could write the parameter in all the controllers that use the table but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way so the application is easier to manage?

Comment: You could redirect EF to a view instead of the table.

Comment: I was considering that but I wish to use the fk relationships unless there is a way to set up relationships between tables and views in EF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner way would be writing a function in the Data Layer to get the objects with a certain filter.

```
public List<Venue> void GetVenuesBeforeYear(int year)
{
    List<Venue> venuesBefore2014 = db.Venues.Where(i => i.Year <=2014).ToList();
    return venuesBefore2014;
}
```

then use the helper function directly from your contrller.